# Where does the "Run Python" button at the top-right of the editor come from?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening a Python file in vscode, I see an overlay in the upper right corner of the window that allows me to directly run the program:

[image]

**Where does this overlay comes from?**

- from an extension specific to Python?
- from something that leverage tasks and allows for such display?
- something else?

I am asking because it would be great to have such a shortcut in other programming languages (Go in my case) to quickly launch (something, usually to run a program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality comes from [the `ms-python.python` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

You can verify for yourself: Disable the extension, then do the required IDE reload, then observe that that button is gone. Then enable the extension and observe that it is back.

There's even a corresponding command that you can use in the command palette: [Straight from the extension docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python#useful-commands):

> `Python: Run Python File in Terminal`
>
> Runs the active Python file in the VS Code terminal. You can also run a Python file by right-clicking on the file and selecting `Run Python File in Terminal`.

Note: Since you mentioned:

> I am asking because it would be great to have such a shortcut in other programming languages (Go in my case) to quickly launch (something, usually to run a program)

Since this is functionality provided by an extension, you're "at the mercy" of whatever the extension devlopers actually want to implement, and whether such a feature actually makes sense for a given language.

Such a "run file" button would very natural for languages that lend themselves toward scripting, but less so for languages geared toward larger projects where it's not statistically normal for a file to "have a main function".